# Cannot delete email forwarders in cPanel?

Tags: cpanel

I cannot delete Forwarders, only add more. I constantly get this error message, where 1st line suggests success but then last row failure

> Email Forwarding Maintenance
>
> The system will no longer forward email for “xxx@gmail.com” to “juniori@zzz.fi”.
>
> Unable to locate the forwarder “juniori@zzz.fi” for account “xxx@gmail.com” on domain “gmail.com” on domain: zzz.fi

I cannot find any files neither where forward list is suggested , e.g. nor dir like /etc/valiases/...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Cpanel > open File Manager > ETC (left side) > open folder of said Domain > @pwcache

That is where the actual users are stored. Delete it from there.

Comment: "@pwcache" would seem to be a password cache for the mailboxes, it doesn't list "forwarders"?